# Multiple jQuery versions [advice]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to hear your advice on the matter i'm about to describe.

I'm part of the development team of a large web app, that makes medium to heavy use of jQuery, being continuously developed for the last 7-8 years. As a consequence of the long lifetime, during that period, many versions of jQuery have been released and used in the app.

Since there is the chance of incompatibilities between versions, what's your advice on developing features that require jQuery?

1. Include a specific version of jQuery in each page where it is used?
2. Include a generic jQuery.js file, that gets continuously updated to the latest version?
3. Something else?

Both alternatives have pros and cons but i would much like to hear your experience on similar situations.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Option 2, of course. And if after an update you have an incompability, you should fix it.

Comment: Use one version of jQuery and one version only. It should be either 1.11 if you need legacy browser support, or 2.x if not, and make sure you keep upgrading the latter if you choose that version.

Comment: From 2006 to 2012(6 years, the same period you mentioned) the framework changed its version 9 times, so you would have at least 9 versions of jquery in your app. [Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery#Release_history).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a specific version of jQuery that's consistent across pages (don't use different versions on different pages). Update as proactively as you reasonably can. It's rare that jQuery releases actually break backward-compatibility, and when they do, it's documented in the blog post announcing the release.

*How* you do that is up to you. Typically it's best to serve unchanging files with far-future caching headers and a specific filename, e.g. `jquery-1.11.2.js`, even though it's a bit of a pain to update that everywhere when updating to a new release. That's so you can get use from the browser cache, but guarantee update when the file actually does change. (Because you change the name.)

That `jquery-1.11.2.js` can be a file you serve from your own server, or from a CDN using a fully-qualified version number (for instance, with Google's CDN, it would be `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js`; with jQuery's [MaxCDN], it would be `//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js`). Using a CDN has the advantage of possibly being used by other sites and so possibly *already* being in cache (and if not, you still benefit from edge-caching); and of course also has the disadvantage of relying on that CDN. (You can do the fallback thing if the CDN fails, but if the CDN is down, the failure may take a while and users may get frustrated and leave. But [that doesn't happen very often at all](http://royal.pingdom.com/2012/07/24/best-cdn-for-jquery-in-2012/).)

If serving yourself, consider bundling jQuery along with all of your other minified JavaScript into a single file, to minimize HTTP requests. E.g., either:

```
<!-- Using a CDN -->
<script src="//the-cdn.example.com/path/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="your-site-v23.js"></script>
```

or

```
<!-- Serving yourself -->
<script src="your-site-v23-including-jquery.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -3):

The best choice is ofcourse to allways use the latest version of jQuery because (mostly) all the updates are usefull. In a perfect world you should then update your code to be compatible with the latest version, but thats up to you and your timeframe/spending.

Comment: Dont mess with your code just because a third party deceided to release software that's not backwards compatable.